# S3 upload from browser with presigned URL and SSE-C - 307 and 403s

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

Here's my scenario:

- using a server to generate presigned URLs that are sent down to the browser on-demand. The browser uploads files to these URLs and then sends the results of the uploads to the server (to avoid making those files cross our load balancers etc.). I keep getting 307s and CORS failures
- the files are encrypted using SSE-C and placed in a bucket that has a private ACL. The signed urls are generated w/ the first snipped and utilized with the second

**Server**

```
const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: objectKey,
        Expires: expiration,
        SSECustomerAlgorithm: 'AES256',
        SSECustomerKey: ssecKey,
        SSECustomerKeyMD5: ssecMD5,
        Metadata: { filename, userId }
    };
    return S3Module.S3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
```

**Client**

```
    // ...
    uploadToS3(url, file, params) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const customHeaders = {
                    'x-amz-meta-filename': params['x-amz-meta-filename'],
                    'x-amz-meta-userId': params['x-amz-meta-userId'],
                    'x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm':
                        params['x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm'],
                    'x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key': params['x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key'],
                    'x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-MD5':
                        params['x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-MD5'],
                    'x-amz-acl': 'private'
                };
                superagent
                    .put(url)
                    .withCredentials()
                    .set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
                    .set(customHeaders)
                    .send(file)
                    .end((err, res) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return reject(err);
                        }
                        console.error(res, err);
                        resolve(res);
                    });
            });
        }
    // ...
```

I keep getting a 307 back from S3, which won't work with CORS of course. I've done some reading and some people said that it was a temporary issue related to DNS sync on the S3 but it doesn't seem to have passed even when waiting for 24+ hours.

- The CORS config is as follows:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
      <CORSRule>
          <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
          <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
          <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
      </CORSRule>
  </CORSConfiguration>
  ```

If I replace the us-west-2 region (to get `https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com`), I get a `403 forbidden response`. If I don't, I get a 307 for https://bucket-name.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com. The browser (rightly) complains with:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'MY URL' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`

Any help would be really appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Browser-based SSE-C seems very sketchy, with so much handling of the encryption key taking place.  I have trouble imagining any value, there...  But, on topic, the 307 issue is indeed a temporary issue after bucket creation that will resolve itself, and in fact should already have done so by now.  Have you verified that you don't have some local DNS caching interfering?  `dig` the bucket hostname. The response would be `CNAME` `s3-us-west-2-w.amazonaws.com` if the DNS update has occurred.

Comment: Yeah I'm w/ you on the browser-based SS3-C - we didn't see the tiny paragraph at the end of one of the S3 docs on it that warns against it till partway through lol. But  re: the 307 - seems to persist even multiple days later. Currently thinking it's something to do w/ a CORS setup because it will work for some team members but not others and then again sometimes for me but not always. Smells like race a race condition/shared problem to me now